# Using an adapter for two different situations

Tags: java, android, android-layout, treeview, android-adapter

I have a regular `RecyclerView` adapter that looks like this:

```
public class MessageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MessageAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private static final String TAG = "MessageAdapter";

    private Context context;

    private List<Message> messages;

    public MessageAdapter(Context context, List<Message> messages) {
        this.context = context;
        this.messages = messages;
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public Message message;

        public TextView messageUser, messageText, messageTime;

        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);

            messageUser = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.messageUser);
            messageText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.messageText);
            messageTime = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.messageTime);
        }

        public void setMessage(Message message) {
            this.message = message;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.message_layout, parent, false);

        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);

        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Message message = messages.get(position);

        holder.setMessage(message);

        holder.messageUser.setText(message.getUser());
        holder.messageText.setText(message.getText());
        holder.messageTime.setText(message.getTime());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return messages.size();
    }

}
```

I use this adapter to list all messages the user has received in the main activity.

In addition to this, I am using the [AndroidTreeView library](https://github.com/bmelnychuk/AndroidTreeView) in a different part of my app that also displays the user's messages (but in a treeview layout).

However, reading the documentation of this library, it says that in order to create an adapter for the treeview data, it must have the following format (taken from the docs):

```
public class MyHolder extends TreeNode.BaseNodeViewHolder<IconTreeItem> {
    ...
    @Override
    public View createNodeView(TreeNode node, IconTreeItem value) {
        final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_profile_node, null, false);
        TextView tvValue = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.node_value);
        tvValue.setText(value.text);

        return view;
    }
    ...
    public static class IconTreeItem {
        public int icon;
        public String text;
    }
}
```

So I created a second message adapter (specifically for the AndroidTreeView library) that looks like this:

```
public class MessageTreeAdapter extends TreeNode.BaseNodeViewHolder<MessageTreeAdapter.TreeItem> {

    private TextView messageUser;
    private TextView messageText;
    private TextView messageTime;

    public MessageTreeAdapter(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public View createNodeView(TreeNode node, TreeItem value) {
        final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.message_layout, null, false);

        Message message = value.message;

        messageUser = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.messageUser);
        messageText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.messageText);
        messageTime = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.messageTime);

        messageUser.setText(message.getUser());
        messageText.setText(message.getText());
        messageTime.setText(message.getTime());

        return view;
    }

    public static class TreeItem {
        public Message message;

        public TreeItem(Message message) {
            this.message = message;
        }
    }
}
```

But as you can see, I'm repeating what I already have in my first adapter, `MessageAdapter.java`. I want to avoid this.

So my question is, how can I use a single adapter (`MessageAdapter.java`) for both situations so that I don't have to repeat any code.

Comment: woah, it was going fine then it exploded into messiness. By using industry general practice of readability, keep adapter do their jobs and holder to do their jobs.  In other words, your code can be rearranged to view classes and in java, interface and reuse is much more practical. just a lot of dissection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a third class that contains all your shared logic and have your adapters [delegate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern) to it.

Personally, I usually create custom view classes when using adapters, which contain all the view related code. Keeps the adapters simple, and makes it easy to reuse the view in different contexts (like in this case different lists/adapters)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Can you please provide an example of how you "create custom view classes" and use them across multiple adapters?

Comment: @user7586924 you can start by googgling "create custom view"

Comment: I've created custom views before, but I don't understand how I can use that to my advantage here.

Comment: In short, you need two different adapters, that is unavoidable. But you can move all your findViewById and setText stuff into a separate class (like for example a MessageView that just takes a message object and updates a couple of internal text views), so you don't have to duplicate that code in both adapters.